# c++ the use of understanding pointers

Tags: c++

I am reading up on c++ pointers.
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
    int * p1, * p2;
    p1 = &firstvalue;  // store the address of firstvalue = 5
    p2 = &secondvalue; // store the adrees of secondvalue = 15
    *p1 = 10;          // p1 = 10 
    *p2 = *p1;         // p2 = 10
    p1 = p2;           // p1 = 10
    *p1 = 20;          // p1 = 20

    cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << '\n';
    cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

from my understanding the output should be

```
   firstvalue is 20
   secondvalue is 10
```

but when I look at the answers it will the other way round

```
   firstvalue is 10
   secondvalue is 20
```

I don't understand quite well about pointers. please help

Comment: Rewrite your comments to keep track of which variable is being written to on each line (based on what each pointer is pointing to at that time), and it should be clear why you get the result you see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
p1 = p2;           // p1 now points to where p2 was pointing at
*p1 = 20;          // *p2 = secondvalue = 20
```

Comment: `p1` doesn't point to `p2`. It now has the same value as `p2` and points to what `p2` is pointing to.

Answer (score 4):

The comments in your code `// p1 = 10`, etc. are all lies. Rewrite them using `firstvalue` and `secondValue` instead, so that they do not lie.

The pointers themselves `p1` and `p2` are *never* 10 or 20. They are the addresses of variables, which are typically long values expressed in hexadecimal notation and of no interest to you. Therefore, each comment of the form `// p1 = 10`, etc., is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, to understand this line:

```
*p1 = 10;
```

Work out where `p1` is pointing:

```
* p1 = 10 ;   // firstvalue = 10
```

And follow the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
int * p1, * p2;
p1 = &firstvalue;  // store the address of firstvalue = 5
p2 = &secondvalue; // store the adrees of secondvalue = 15


*p1 = 10;          // value of p1 = firstValue = 10  
*p2 = *p1;         // value of p2 = secondvalue = 10
p1 = p2;           // p1 points to memory location refered by p2 which is secondValue. 
*p1 = 20;          // p1 = secondvalue = 20
```

So at end of all operation firstvalue = 10; secondvalue = 20